# What was the butcher's bill in the aftermath of the 1998 3-3 class' calamity?

Tags: another

How many students, relatives died? How many survived?

Use this template. List names if you feel so (would like, but a body count is fine)

Teacher 2.
Relatives __
Students __
Survivors __

Comment: while not in the format you want the [Wikia](http://another.wikia.com/wiki/Deaths) has a summary for the listed years though it doesn't list survivors

Comment: I supposed there would be such a list. 